# powerbuilder target deployed as smart-client

Tags: powerbuilder, smartclient

Im new to powerbuilder 12.5, and to be honest, its my first time to use powerbuilder series as winform development medium. Back in my PB training, i have remember that since pb 11 you can deploy the pb app as smart-client.

My problem is my PB App is a PB target and to use the smart-client deployment feature, i should use .Net target. The app i am going to deploy is already finished and i managed to create installer for the end users.

so my questions are:

1. Can I publish my PB app as smart-client and how?
2. Is there any open source/free third party smart-client/intelligent updater out there

Comment: I haven't used the smart client (click once?) feature in PB (haven't used PB lately either.) But from what I remember about PB you can have a PB target and a .NET target of the same application. Not sure how well that works in real life, but theoretically you can compile an app that was built as a PB app as a PB Winforms app.

Comment: i have read about that but it seems, having a .net target inside the pb target causes some unknown error and my supervisor didnt recommend it to be used. but as a work around, we have created a bat file where the users can execute to copy the updates. thank you @Slapout !